# Промис не срабатывает повторно, даже если он подменен свежим

Tags: javascript, promise

Есть класс `A`, создание экземпляра которого запускает какие-то "фоновые" процессы. Эти процессы генерируют события, на которые должно быть можно "подписаться"

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }
}

let a = new A();

a.when.ready.then(() => {
  console.log("ready");
});
```

Для этого я создал статический метод `registerEventResolvers`, к которому в конструкторе и обращаюсь

```
class A {
  static registerEventResolvers(instance) {
    instance.when = {}; // сюда помещаем зарегистрированные события, на которые можно "подписываться" с помощью `when`
    instance.resolvers = {}; // а сюда будем сохранять резолверы промисов, чтобы их [промисы] можно было резолвить извне

    let registerEventResolver = (event) => { // функция, которая вызывается ниже 
      let promise = new Promise(res => { // создаем промис
        instance.resolvers[event] = res; // а резолвер помещаем в свойство `resolvers` инстанса, т.е. чтобы можно было вызывать `a.resolvers["ready"]()`
      });

      promise.then(() => { // (*) вот тут ключевой момент
        registerEventResolver(event);
      });

      instance.when[event] = promise; // сохраняем, чтобы можно было делать `a.when.ready.then()`
    };

    [ // список известных (разрешенных) событий, на которые можно будет подписываться
      "ready",
      "error",
      // "..."
    ].forEach(event => {
      registerEventResolver(event); // для каждого из них сохраняем резолвер
    });
  }

  constructor() {
    A.registerEventResolvers(this);
  }
}
```

В общем и целом это работает

```js
class A {
  static registerEventResolvers(instance) {
    instance.when = {};
    instance.resolvers = {};

    let registerEventResolver = (event) => {
      let promise = new Promise(res => {
        instance.resolvers[event] = res;
      });

      promise.then(() => {
        registerEventResolver(event);
      });

      instance.when[event] = promise;
    };

    [
      "ready",
      "error",
    ].forEach(event => {
      registerEventResolver(event);
    });
  }

  constructor() {
    A.registerEventResolvers(this);
    
    // ...
    
    this.resolvers["ready"]();
  }
}

let a = new A();

a.when.ready.then(() => {
  console.log("ready");
});
```

Однако **проблема** возникает тогда, когда я повторно выбрасываю то же событие - **оно просто не срабатывает**

```js
class A {
  static registerEventResolvers(instance) {
    instance.when = {};
    instance.resolvers = {};

    let registerEventResolver = (event) => {
      let promise = new Promise(res => {
        instance.resolvers[event] = res;
      });

      promise.then(() => {
        registerEventResolver(event);
      });

      instance.when[event] = promise;
    };

    [
      "ready",
      "error",
    ].forEach(event => {
      registerEventResolver(event);
    });
  }

  constructor() {
    A.registerEventResolvers(this);
    
    // ...
    
    this.resolvers["ready"]();
    this.resolvers["ready"]();
  }
}

let a = new A();

console.log("Подписались один раз, но заэмиттили дважды, поэтому должно вывести \"ready\" 2 раза, но выводит только 1");

a.when.ready.then(() => {
  console.log("ready");
});
```

То, что промис не может перейти из `settled` состояния снова в `pending` - это ясно как день. Именно поэтому я и добавил вот эти строчки, которые *подменяют* промис свежим после того как тот зарезолвился (чтобы его (ну правда уже как бы не его, а другой) можно было снова зарезолвить)

```
promise.then(() => { // (*) вот тут ключевой момент
  registerEventResolver(event);
});
```

Я таким образом рассчитывал, что когда промис зарезолвится, то он просто подменится заново созданным и при повторном вызове его резолвера сработает тот же `then`, что уже был навешан на инстанс извне. Но этого не происходит.

Почему так, я понимаю не совсем. И это **1-ое**, что интересует. **2-ое**, очевидно, что с этим делать (если вообще что-то можно).

Рискну предположить, что проблему можно каким-то образом решить при помощи генераторов, но не уверен, поэтому не хотелось бы тратить время впустую, чтобы снова опростоволоситься. Так что прошу помощи.

Comment: Зачем натягивать сову на глобус? Нужно просто взять EventEmitter https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Comment: @AlexeyTen это не node :) Вообще согласен с тем, что архитектура event emitter'а (в моей такой реализации) довольно сомнительна, поэтому я готов выслушать другие предложения. Но хотелось бы сперва заставить работать мой код (если это возможно), чтобы разобраться что к чему

Comment: @AlexeyTen или подождите, я что, могу нодовскую либу в браузер подтянуть выходит? О_О

Comment: Насколько я помню он на js написан. Ну и в npm есть аналоги я полагаю. Я не имел в виду брать именно нодовский, я про то, что вы хотите явно не промис, а как раз таки события

Comment: Оно и не сработает потому что `a.when.ready.then()` ссылается на первый промис. Попробуйте разобраться c паттерном Pub/Sub.